# Django: Auto Instantiation of custom primary key?

Tags: python, django

I have a class with a custom pk field, and a classmethod to generate this special pk:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    custom_pk = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    other_attr = ...

    @classmethod
    def gen_id(cls):
        # ...
        return the_id
```

Now, I suppose I can create object (in a view for example) doing this:

```
Card.objects.create(custom_pk=Card.gen_id(), other_attr="foo")
```

But I'd like to have the same result using the classic way to do it:

```
Card.objects.create(other_attr="foo")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) signal to supply your primary key is missing. This signal handler will be called before each call to `Card.save()` method, therefore we need to make sure that we won't override `custom_pk` if already set:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Card)
def add_auto_pk(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.custom_pk:
        instance.custom_pk = Card.get_id()
```

See [Django signal documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) for more details.

Comment: Thx. didn't thought of that.